# Is it okay to generate popup from toggle switch?

Tags: gui-design, mobile, buttons, user-expectation, ux-field

For one of my page, I am going to use a switch for a yes or no question. However, that particular question requires a confirmation popup if it the switch 'turned on'. Is it appropriate in UX view?

What do you think?

If the switch is on -> generate 'Are you sure you want to do that?' confirmation popup:

[image]

Comment: Can you elaborate on what happens when this switch is toggled? Why you think you need to ask for confirmation? Right now, this seems like either a badly labeled switch ("change courier -> yes/no"? Into what?), or like something that should be a view toggle instead of a switch (e.g. a disclosure triangle), or a pushbutton (if it actually requires confirmation, it's usually behind a pushbutton because it's a larger, dangerous *action*, not just an on/off switch)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While a dialog is permissible under extreme circumstances, you may want to ask yourself if a softer UI prompt makes more sense. For example:

- After initial toggle, show text under the toggle:

  - "Are you sure? Click the toggle again to finalize change"

It's also common for items that could have a large repercussion to prompt for a typed message to complete the action:

[image]

Lastly, are you sure you're using the right UI component for the change that needs to be made? "Change Courier" does note feel like a `yes/no` `on/off` question. Would it be more appropriate to prompt this action with a button and an appropriate follow-up depending on the weight of the decision?

Answer (score 2):

**It is recommended to use a confirmation dialog when the action is critical and requires the user's attention**, for example: delete resources, section's expired, and others. If your action is not critical and the dialog is unnecessary, the use of dialog is not recommended, because it causes interruption of the task and annoy the user.

In a switch, the user can do and undo the action at any time, so it is not critical. What you need to make clear to the user is the consequence of toggle activation.

So make sure the dialog is really necessary :)

I hope it helps.